# How to create an instance of type T at runtime with TypeTags

Tags: scala, reflection

Here below is how to create a new instance of type T at runtime with `Manifest`:

```
trait MyTrait
class MyClass1(val name: String) extends MyTrait
class MyClass2(val name: String) extends MyTrait

class Test[T <: MyTrait] {

  def createInstance[T](name: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    m.runtimeClass.getConstructors()(0)
      .newInstance(name).asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  def doSomething() {
    val myClass = createInstance("joe")
    ...
  }
}

...

val test = new Test[MyClass1]
test.doSomething
```

The `createInstance` method above creates a new instance of one of the classes that implement `MyTrait` and invokes the constructor with the given string. How do I implement the same with `TypeTag`?

---

**Reimplemented using scala.reflect.runtime._**

Here below is class `Test` reimplemented as suggested by som-snytt:

```
class Test[T <: MyTrait] {

  import scala.reflect.runtime._
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def createInstance[T: TypeTag](name: String): T = {
    val tt = typeTag[T]

    currentMirror.reflectClass(tt.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass).reflectConstructor(
      tt.tpe.members.filter(m =>
        m.isMethod && m.asMethod.isConstructor
      ).iterator.next.asMethod
    )(name).asInstanceOf[T]
  }   
}
```

As long as I call `createInstance` on `Test` it works:

```
val test = new Test[MyClass1]
val myClass = test.createInstance("hello") // this works
```

But as soon as I define a new class derived from `Test`...

```
class DerivedTest[T <: MyTrait] extends Test[T]
```

... and I invoke `createInstance` on that new class like this...

```
val test = new DerivedText[MyClass1]
val myClass = test.createInstance("hello") // this crashes
```

... I get the following error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqLike$$anon$1.next(LinearSeqLike.scala:62)
    at DerivedTest$class.createInstance(<console>:27)
    at $anon$1.createInstance(<console>:26)
    at .<init>(<console>:28)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
...
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `T` in `createInstance` method shadows `T` in `Test` class. This is probably not what you meant.

Comment: Yes, @ghik told you not to shadow the T. Here, you supply a type param to the ctor but not to createInstance.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... but createInstance should create instances of type T in the 'Test' class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually here is the implementation that actually works - please just assume this answer comes from **som-snytt**:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class Test[T <: MyTrait : TypeTag] {

  def createInstance(args: AnyRef*)(ctor: Int = 0): T = {
    val tt = typeTag[T]

    currentMirror.reflectClass(tt.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass).reflectConstructor(
      tt.tpe.members.filter(m =>
        m.isMethod && m.asMethod.isConstructor
      ).iterator.toSeq(ctor).asMethod
    )(args: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }   
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: You only need a type param on either Test or createInstance. If on Test, unnecessary to have val tt, or make it a def. The TypeTag becomes an implicit class param, `class Test[T]()(implicit x: TypeTag[T])`. As a type bound, as you show it, you can implicitly[TypeTag[T]] to get it.

Comment: Yes... you're right... I was a bit tired last night. Fixed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone who does this all the time can chime in, but it took me this many steps to reproduce it.

I start the REPL -i, so autocomplete is broken.  That puts me at a disadvantage.

```
scala> class X(i: Int)
defined class X

scala> typeTag[X]
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[X] = TypeTag[X]

scala> .tpe
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = X

scala> .members
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = Scopes(constructor X, value i, method $asInstanceOf, method $isInstanceOf, method synchronized, method ##, method !=, method ==, method ne, method eq, constructor Object, method notifyAll, method notify, method clone, method getClass, method hashCode, method toString, method equals, method wait, method wait, method wait, method finalize, method asInstanceOf, method isInstanceOf, method !=, method ==)

scala> res2.filter(s => s.isMethod && s.asMethod.isConstructor)
res4: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(constructor X, constructor Object)

scala> res4.iterator.next
res7: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = constructor X

scala> .typeSignature
res8: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = (i: scala.Int)X

scala> res7.asMethod
res11: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = constructor X

scala> res1.typeSymbol.asClass
res13: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = class X

scala> currentMirror reflectClass res13
res14: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassMirror = class mirror for X (bound to null)

scala> res14 reflectConstructor res11
res16: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror = constructor mirror for X.<init>(i: scala.Int): X (bound to null)

scala> res16(7)
res17: Any = X@28730c5a

scala> .asInstanceOf[X]
res18: X = X@28730c5a
```

Comment: Yes, at the moment this is verbose. Will be fixed in https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8221.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako You are always one step ahead of us SO monkeys. Sometimes two steps.

Comment: Tx... this works as long as I do not invoke createInstance method from a derived class. If I invoke createInstance from a derived class, I always get error java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator because it does not find the constructor.

Comment: @j3d if I understand you, yes, you must invoke `createInstance[MyClass1]` so it knows what you're reflecting. You can't assume it's inferring the type you want.

Comment: I've just updated my post with more details. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

j3d,

I believe the manifest approach is deprecated.
You can use scala code below to create an instance via reflection.
You will have to adjust the code slightly to factor for classes with multiple constructors, and/or arguments

Code is based on http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import ru._

...

class Person { }


def example() = 
{
   val instance1 = createInstance[Person]()
   val instance2 = createInstance(typeOf[Person])
}


def createInstance[T:TypeTag]() : Any= {
    createInstance(typeOf[T])
}


def createInstance(tpe:Type): Any = {
    val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val clsSym = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
    val clsMirror = mirror.reflectClass(clsSym)
    val ctorSym = tpe.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val ctorMirror = clsMirror.reflectConstructor(ctorSym)
    val instance = ctorMirror()
    return instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object BeanFactory {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

  def createBean[T: TypeTag](): Option[T] = {
    val typee = ru.typeOf[T]
    val constructor = typee.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    if (constructor.isPrivate) {
      println("private class can not created ")
      None
    } else {
      val classMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflectClass(typee.typeSymbol.asClass)
      val constructorMethod = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructor)
      val params = constructor.paramLists.flatten.map(par => {
        if (par.typeSignature =:= typeOf[Int]) {
          0
        } else {
          if (par.typeSignature =:= typeOf[String]) {
            ""
          } else {
            if (par.typeSignature =:= typeOf[Double]) {
              0.0
            } else {
              if (par.typeSignature =:= typeOf[Float]) {
                0.0f
              } else {
                if (par.typeSignature =:= typeOf[Char]) {
                  ""
                } else {
                  if (par.typeSignature =:= typeOf[Boolean]) {
                    false
                  } else {
                    null
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

      })
      Some(constructorMethod(params: _*).asInstanceOf[T])
    }
  }
}
```

**This may end up with your problem**