# Anonynomus derivation from T in generic function

Tags: scala, generics

I'd like to implement a generic function that provides an anonymous derived class from `T` that provides an implementation of some certain function.

I'd like it to be like:

```
def impl[T]  = new T{def f = 1}
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
<console>:11: error: class type required but T found
       def impl[T]  = new T{def f = 1}
```

Is there any way to do it without reflection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715164/how-to-create-an-instance-of-type-t-at-runtime-with-typetags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591957/class-type-required-but-t-found