# Can Scala Companion Object Traits call a constructor of the class?

Tags: scala, traits

I'm trying to solve a problem that may not be possible in Scala.

I want to have a Trait to solve default constructors

```scala
trait Builder[T <: Buildable] {
  def build(code: String): T = new T(code)
  def build: T = new T("bar")
}
```

So extending the Trait on the companion object automatically has access to functions that creates the class with specific constructors and parameters

```scala
class A(code: String) extends Buildable

object A extends Builder[A]
```

Extending the Trait, the companion object has the constructors

```scala
A.build("foo")
A.build
```

Is this possible in Scala?

Also tried abstract classes, but hadn't had any success

```scala
trait Builder[T <: BuildableClass] {
  def build(code: String): T = new T(code)
  def build: T = new T("bar")
}

abstract class BuildableClass(code: String)

class A(code: String) extends BuildableClass(code)

object A extends Builder[A]
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: currently locked on Scala 2.12

Comment: The answer might depend on whether you're on 2.14 or 3 or something else. Do you have any constraints regarding the version on which it has to work?

Comment: Currently working on Scala 2.12

Comment: There is no way to abstract over constructors, you would need to duplicate that bit or generate using macros / reflection / implicits. - However, one approach that sometimes works for me is `trait FooCompanion[F <: Foo] extends (Args => F)` where `Args` are the common arguments of all `Foo` subtypes and then if a `Foo` subtype is a `case class` its companion object will implement the logic for me so I have to do is `object FooSubType extends FooCompanion[FooSubtype]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much cleaner solution to this problem without using macros / reflection / implicits

```
trait Buildable

trait Builder[T <: Buildable] {
  self =>
  def apply(code: String): T

  def build: T = self.apply("foo")

  def build(code: String): T = self.apply(code)
}


case class A(code: String) extends Buildable {
  def getCode: String = code
}

object A extends Builder[A]

A.build("bar").getCode
A.build.getCode
```

Comment: Well, actually, it's not clear why you needed `Builder`/`Buildable` at all (especially if you make the class a case class): `case class A(code: String = "foo")` `A("bar").code` `A().code`

Answer (score 1):

One of the potential solution that uses a reflection looks a bit ugly, but it works.

```scala
import scala.reflect._

trait Builder[T <: Buildable] {
  def build(code: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): T =
    ct.runtimeClass.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(code).asInstanceOf[T]

  def build(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): T =
    ct.runtimeClass.getConstructors()(0).newInstance("bar").asInstanceOf[T]
}

trait Buildable

class A(code: String) extends Buildable {
  def getCode = code
}

object A extends Builder[A]

val a: A = A.build
println(a.getCode)
```

The problem is that your `Builder` trait doesn't know anything about how to construct your instances. You can get this info from runtime with reflection or from compile time with macros.

Comment: This solution using reflection is solving the problem, so definitely will be my way to go, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the type erasure, in ordinary code `new T` is allowed only for class type `T`, not an abstract type/type parameter.

[In Scala, is it possible to instantiate an object of generic type T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299269/in-scala-is-it-possible-to-instantiate-an-object-of-generic-type-t)

[How to create an instance of type T at runtime with TypeTags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715164/how-to-create-an-instance-of-type-t-at-runtime-with-typetags)

[Class type required but T found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591957/class-type-required-but-t-found)

An alternative to runtime reflection (see @StanislavKovalenko's answer) is macros. `new T` is possible there because during macro expansion `T` is not erased yet.

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox // libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value

abstract class BuildableClass(code: String)
  
trait Builder[T <: BuildableClass] {
  def build(code: String): T = macro BuilderMacros.buildImpl[T]
  def build: T = macro BuilderMacros.buildDefaultImpl[T]
}

class BuilderMacros(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def buildImpl[T: WeakTypeTag](code: Tree): Tree = q"new ${weakTypeOf[T]}($code)"
  def buildDefaultImpl[T: WeakTypeTag]: Tree = q"""new ${weakTypeOf[T]}("bar")"""
}
```

```scala
// in a different subproject 

class A(code:String) extends BuildableClass(code)

object A extends Builder[A]

A.build("foo") // scalac: new A("foo")
A.build // scalac: new A("bar")
```

Alternative implementations:

```scala
trait Builder[T <: BuildableClass] {
  def build(code: String): T = macro BuilderMacros.buildImpl
  def build: T = macro BuilderMacros.buildDefaultImpl
}

class BuilderMacros(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  val tpe = c.prefix.tree.tpe.baseType(symbolOf[Builder[_]]).typeArgs.head
  def buildImpl(code: Tree): Tree = q"new $tpe($code)"
  def buildDefaultImpl: Tree = q"""new $tpe("bar")"""
}
```

```scala
class BuilderMacros(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  val symb = c.prefix.tree.symbol.companion
  def buildImpl(code: Tree): Tree = q"new $symb($code)"
  def buildDefaultImpl: Tree = q"""new $symb("bar")"""
}
```

```scala
class BuilderMacros(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  val tpe = c.prefix.tree.tpe.companion
  def buildImpl(code: Tree): Tree = q"new $tpe($code)"
  def buildDefaultImpl: Tree = q"""new $tpe("bar")"""
}
```

```scala
class BuilderMacros(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  val tpe = symbolOf[Builder[_]].typeParams.head.asType.toType
    .asSeenFrom(c.prefix.tree.tpe, symbolOf[Builder[_]])
  def buildImpl(code: Tree): Tree = q"new $tpe($code)"
  def buildDefaultImpl: Tree = q"""new $tpe("bar")"""
}
```